# Does jQuery validate work in IE8 at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery validate plugin. I tried using it on my own form, and found that in IE8 it was not working. I can't find a definitive answer from the site itself or searching around.

Looking at the [Examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) I can see that they don't work in IE8 either.

So, does this plugin work at all in IE8?

Comment: Yes, the jQuery Validate plugin most certainly works in IE 8... as long as it's really IE 8 and not some other browser in "IE 8 Mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example in IE11 in IE8 mode, it wouldn't work. But using a VM with IE8 *did* work, so I'm noting it here in answer to my own question.

Comment: Yes, this plugin works in IE 8.  You **must** use the actual browser to test.  "IE8 Mode" is not an emulator.  MS provides free virtual hard drive images for use with VPC specifically for website testing.